# External USB3 HDD works in USB 2.0 port, but not in USB 3.0 port

Tags: 14.04, usb, external-hdd

I have a new external HDD designed for USB 3.0, but it only works in my USB 2.0 port.  The computer is a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.

dmesg gives the following error when plugging into USB 3.0 port.

```
[86022.030544] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd 
[86032.041098] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=5106 
[86032.041106] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1 
[86032.041110] usb 4-2: Product: AS2105
[86032.041113] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[86037.038614] usb 4-2: can't set config #1, error -110
```

What is error -110?
Are there any known remedies to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If the device works in a USB-2 port then there's an issue with the xhci driver and your device.

I can't check the xhci source at the moment, but IIRC in ohci error 110 means timeout.
Does the external drive have an ext. power supply? Try to first power up the drive, wait 10 seconds and then connect it to the USB3 port.

Comment: I unplugged it from the working USB 2.0 port and then plugged it into the USB 3.0 port and it worked as expected.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: FYI, errno ETIMEDOUT is 110.

Comment: Err, that's exactly what I wrote??

Comment: You wrote IIRC.  I looked it up and wanted it to be written as a statement if anyone else wants the information.  As you probably know, the xhci driver returns negative errno values, which are easy to lookup.